# Caching if visit same page twice: back button only shows data from second viewing

Tags: html, caching, http-headers

I am creating a webpage and am having some issues with how the back button works on the page. I am guessing that I need to set some headers, but don't know which ones or how. This is what I'm seeing:

(1) Go to the main page, which shows forum threads.

(2) Click a link to go to a page showing a thread. On this page, scroll down and add a comment.

(3) Comment is saved via form (edit: I have tried both POST and GET form). The same thread page is now reloaded via a redirect. The comment shows.

In Chrome: pressing the back button at this point still shows the comment as having been added. It looks as though the back button didn't work. However, the page is scrolled down as it was for (2). Clicking the back button again shows the main page. So, the back button does take me back, but if the same page is there twice, it shows the new data both times.

In IE9: pressing the back button displays "Webpage has expired". Clicking it again takes me to the main page.

How do I alter this behavior so the back button truly shows me the previous page?

(The reason I'm doing this is that I keep track of how many pages I am from the main page so I can generate a "back to main page" link. (2) above has history.go(-1) and (3) above has history.go(-2). This won't work if the user presses the browser back button from (3) since it will now be 1 away from the main page, but show the link from (3).

Comment: pure HTML is used? try setting the flag in cookie by JavaScript. Modern browsers handle "Back" button with different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In step (3) you probably have a POST that returns the new HTML of the thread page.  Instead the POST should redirect to a GET of the thread page.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: The comments form is a POST. Once the comment has been saved, I do use a GET redirect to go back to the threads page. I have just now tried to change the comments form to a GET. The result is the same. I see from your link that the browser does this to avoid going back to a form, which could then be submitted twice. But I'd still like to be able to do it.

Comment: Actually, it is best to use POST for the form as you had it originally.  And it seems you were already following the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern, so I guess that was not the problem.